# jsf dialog box does not show selected record in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog

I want to display a datatable and once an entry is selected, its content should be displayed in a separate dialog box.
My code is like this.

```
<h:form id="form">  
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />  
        <p:dataTable id="PMDatas" var="pMData" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" value="#
{managedBean.dataModel}" paginator="true" rows="100"  
                     selection="#{managedBean.selectedRecord}" 
selectionMode="single">  

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onRowSelect}"   
                update=":form:display :form:msgs" oncomplete="moreviewDialog.show()" 
/>  
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{managedBean.onRowUnselect}" 
update=":form:msgs"/>  

    <p:column headerText="#">  
         #{rowIndex+1}
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Cell Name">  
        <h:outputText value="#{pMData.cellid}" />  
    </p:column>  




        </p:dataTable>  


        <p:dialog header="History Data" widgetVar="moreviewDialog" resizable="false" 
id="moreviewDlg"  
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">  

    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">  

      <h:outputText value="CellId:" />  
      <h:outputText value="#{managedBean.selectedRecord.cellid}" style="font-
weight:bold"/>  


    </h:panelGrid>  

        </p:dialog>  

</h:form>
```

my pMData class is like below.

```
public class PMData implements Serializable{
public PMData(String cell) {

    cellid=cell;

}

private String cellid;

public void setCellid(String cellid){
    this.cellid=cellid;
}



public String getCellid(){

    return cellid;
}
}
```

and PMDataModel class is like this.

```
public class PMDataModel   extends ListDataModel<PMData> implements SelectableDataModel<PMData> ,Serializable{

/**
 * Creates a new instance of PMDataModel
 */
public PMDataModel(){
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(PMData object) {
    return object.getCellid();
}

@Override
public PMData getRowData(String rowKey) {

    List<PMData> data = (List<PMData>) getWrappedData();  

    for(PMData entry: data) {  
        if(entry.getCellid().equals(rowKey))  
            return entry;  
    }  

    return null;  
}

 public PMDataModel(List<PMData> data) {  
    super(data);  
 }
}
```

When I executed this selected entry is displayed in Facesmessages but doesnot appear in dialog box.

my mangedbean  class id like below.

```
private PMDataModel dataModel;
private PMData selectedRecord;
public void setSelectedRecord(PMData selectedRecord){
this.selectedRecord=selectedRecord;

}

public PMData getSelectedRecord(){
return  selectedRecord;
}
public managedBean() {
   dataAll= new ArrayList<PMData>();

   this.getFiles(dataAll);
   dataModel = new PMDataModel(dataAll);

}
public ArrayList<PMData> getDataAll(){

    return dataAll;
}
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  

     System.out.println("inside onRow select  Method");
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Row Selected",  ((PMData)event.getObject()).getCellid());       

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}  

public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {  
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Row Unselected",((PMData)        event.getObject()).getCellid());  

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
} 

public PMDataModel getDataModel() {  
    return dataModel;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mistakenly put Request scope when creating JSF managed classes. After changing it to session scope it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

gosk: I think this will help you. Just replace your update attribute's value

`<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onRowSelect}"

  update="@form :msgs"`.

Comment: Hi Diganta,
It didnt work. I tried like below. 
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update="@form:display @form:msgs" oncomplete="moreviewDialog.show()" />  
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update="@form :msgs"     oncomplete="moreviewDialog.show()" />    
                         
Then selection also become disabled. Is there any other option?

Comment: Have you used two `<p:ajax>` with event `rowSelect`?

Comment: Hi Diganta, I am new to primefaces, I just copied these from primefaces examples. I dont know exactly what you are telling.

Comment: Please see your previous comment , there you have written two `<p:ajax>` with `event` attribute `rowSelect`. So if you do so, then you should delete first `<p:ajax />` and place only last `<p:ajax event="rowSelect">`. Am I clear?

Comment: Now I mean I tried both ways. In first method I did update="@form:display @form:msgs"
In second method i did update="@form :msgs"

Comment: Hi, Is there any other option available?

Comment: This is working correctly for me. I can't understand what is wrong you have done.

Comment: Hi, I changed getSelectedRecord method inside managedBean to get a particular record rather than selected record
public PMData getSelectedRecord(){
        return  dataAll.get(2);
    }
then this record appear perfectly. I dont know why the selected record does not triggered by setSelectedRecord() method

Comment: Can you access your DB from `getRowData(String rowKey)` method? I think at the time of row selection method `getRowData` returns `null`. If so then fetch corresponding record from DB with the help of `rowKey`.

Comment: No, getRowData() method returns selected row perfectly. Only getSelectedRecord() method does not work. How can I use rowKey value to the getSelectedRecord() method.

Comment: Hi Diganta, Can you help me with how to use rowKey value to use with getSelectedRecord() method?

Comment: At the time of row selection any Exception??

Comment: No no exceptions when used getRowData() method

Comment: @gosk If you have no such type of limitation of using `dataModel` , then you can try list type variable instead of datamodel as a `value` attribute of `dataTable`. You can give a look at [*****THIS LINK*****](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27002). and add value of `update` attribute of `p:ajax` `@form`.

Comment: I tried as you said replacing datamodel with list, but still dialog box doesnot show selected record. below is what I changed. <p:dataTable id="PMDatas" var="PMData" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" value="#{managedBean.dataAll}"  rowKey="#{PMData.cellid}" paginator="true" rows="100"  
                         selection="#{managedBean.selectedRecord}" selectionMode="single">  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update="@form" oncomplete="moreviewDialog.show()" />

Comment: sorry, I can't understand why this does not work for you. adding attribute `immediate="true"` `process="PMDatas"` of `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: Still the same result. I cant undestand why.

Comment: I changed setSelectedRecord() method like this. public void setSelectedRecord(PMData selectedRecord1){
       this.selectedRecord=selectedRecord1;
       
       System.out.println("inside setselected Method"+ selectedRecord.getCellid());
        
    } then it outputs the selected entry perfeclty. but still getSelectedRecord() method gives null in the dialog box. why is that?

Comment: Changing your `getSelectedRecord()` method into `public PMData getSelectedRecord() {
if(this.selectedRecord == null) {
 System.out.println("Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL");
} else System.out.println("Inside getSelected Record+++++"+this.selectedRecord.getCellid());
  return selectedRecord;
 }` this, and tell what is the output after row selection.

Comment: output is INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL

Comment: I think that means your `setSelectedRecord()` method is not setting proper value into managed bean's 'selectedRecord'. You have property `selectedRecord` if on row selection time `setSelectedRecord()` method sets proper object into `selectedRecord` property then you should get that object from `getSelectedRecord()`.

Comment: Place system.out in both getter and setter of `selectedRecord` property and print the cell value. and send the total output. I wan to see setter works properly but getter is not, as you tell.

Comment: here is output.INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   inside setselected Method: selected recordRNC4/BSC6900UCell:Label=AMKAL2K, CellID=42215
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   inside setselected Method: selected recordRNC4/BSC6900UCell:Label=AMKAL2W, CellID=42211
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   Inside getSelected Record++++++NULL
INFO:   inside setselected Method: selected

Comment: Dear Diganta, I think I solved the problem. I had used request scope in netBeans when creating JSF managed class. Now chnged it to session scope. And it is working now. Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: @gosk I have not solved your problem, you have solved yourself. So my advice is to not select my answer is right(as correct answer). You should answer your own question and choose that as correct answer. One thing you can use `ViewScope` also. Always try to use viewScope,SessionScope instead of RequestScope(except some mandatory case).